# Error only in production: Manifest does not contain a suitable icon

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I am making a PWA but I’m running into some issues. When app is in development mode i get no errors for the PWA but when I push it production I get:

> Web app manifest or service worker do not meet the installability requirements

> Manifest does not contain a suitable icon - PNG, SVG or WebP format of at least 144 px is required, the sizes attribute must be set, and the purpose attribute, if set, must include “any” or “maskable”.

I dont understand why because here is my manifest.json

```
{
  "short_name": "Ionic App",
  "name": "My Ionic App",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/icon/favicon.png",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon",
      "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icon/icon.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "purpose": "maskable"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#ffffff",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is the error message I am currently receiving.

[image]

According to it, the purpose attribute if set should **not** include "maskable."

Comment: For what it's worth, my error turned out to be due to a typo in the "type" attribute for the icon, using a dash instead of a slash.  I had put "image-png" instead of "image/png" for the icon type.